# Spring Rest Issue

Tags: spring, unit-testing, rest

I am getting an error while i am trying to test my "testCreateUser" method using Spring RestApi, the `uploadNewUser.xml` contains the login information about the user and the role.

```
  @Test
  public void testCreateUser() throws Exception {
    Reader reader = getFileReader("src/test/resources/uploadNewUser.xml");
    String input_xml = IOUtils.toString(reader);

    byte[] content = input_xml.getBytes();
    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    request.setContent(content);
    request.setContentType("text/xml");
    request.setMethod(RequestMethod.POST.name());
    request.setRequestURI("/restapi/users/");
    final ModelAndView mav = handle(request, response);
    Map<String, Object> map = mav.getModel();
    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      String key = entry.getKey();
      UserCollection collection = (UserCollection) entry.getValue();
```

org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.error = com.xxx.dashboard.restapi.GlobalResponse@42a4fd6d

**error stack:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xxx.dashboard.restapi.GlobalResponse cannot be cast to com.xxx.dashboard.restapi.UserCollection
```

---

### and i am getting an issue with cannot cast GlobalRespose to UserCollection. can anyone tell me where exactly i am doing is wrong? any help or pointers are most welcome thanks in advance

```
 @Controller("userrestapi")
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/restapi/users/", "/restapi/users" })
    public class UserRestApi extends AbstractBaseApi {
...
         @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
          @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
          public ModelAndView createNewUser(@RequestBody UserCollection userCollection,
              @RequestHeader(value = "accept", required = false) String accept,
              @RequestHeader(value = "version", required = false) String version) {
            try {
              OOUser ooUser = userCollection.getUsers().get(0);
              Mapper mapper = (Mapper) userVersions.get(Constants.USER_DETAIL_VERSION_MAPPER_KEY);
              int userId = usersRestApiService.validateAndCreateNewUser(ooUser, mapper);
              List<FilterField> filterFieldList = new ArrayList<FilterField>();
              filterFieldList.add(new FilterField("userId", String.valueOf(userId)));
              return getUserDetailsForFilter(filterFieldList, accept, version, mapper);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
              logger.warn("Api exception", ex);
              return getModelAndView(accept, "error", getGlobalResponse(ex));
            }
```

the abstractbaseapi contains following

```
public class AbstractBaseApi {

  public static final String XML_VIEW = "apiXmlView";
  public static final String JSON_VIEW = "apiJsonView";
  public static final String JSON_ACCEPT_HEADER = "application/json";
  public static final String JSON_CONTENT_HEADER = "Content-type: application/json";
  public static final String XML_CONTENT_HEADER = "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8";
  public static final int MAX_COUNT = 100;
  public static final String XML_REQUEST_ERROR_FORMAT = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><GlobalResponse xmlns='http://www.operative.com/api' xmlns:v2='http://www.operative.com/api/v2' xmlns:v1='http://www.operative.com/api/v1'> <error errorCode='%1$s' text='%2$s'/> </GlobalResponse>";
  public static final String JSON_REQUEST_ERROR_FORMAT = "{error:{errorCode:'%1$s',text:'%2$s'}}";

  protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

  protected ModelAndView getModelAndView(String accept, String key, Object value) {
    String view = XML_VIEW;

    if (accept != null && accept.toLowerCase().contains(JSON_ACCEPT_HEADER)) {
      view = JSON_VIEW;
    }
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("Accept Header:" + accept + " , generating:" + view);
    }

    return new ModelAndView(view, BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + key, value);
  }
```

Comment: Can you edit it so we can see the code clearly and the error message clearly..

Comment: Hi,Niels,i am edited the post for you to see the error message clearly.

Comment: Could you show your controller method as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your model contains more than you think.

You are going through your model and looking for your user collection. However, the first encountered object in your map seems to be the GlobalResponse map.

You should probably just get it by name from the model, i.e.

```
UserCollection collection = (UserCollection) mav.getModel().get("userCollection");
```

rather than iterating..